# Suspended Facebook Account After Testing Plugin

Tags: facebook, testing

**Problem:**

I am trying to test the subscription to the facebook comment event as described by facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ .

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You commented on: ' + response);
    }
);
```

While I was integration testing this, after 23 comments, I found my account was suspended. I can no longer comment. I attempted to resolve this by logging into my facebook account and reactivating by answering questions (DOB, Captcha) and resetting my password. Unfortunately, this did not allow me to comment again. I thought they me be blocking me by IP.

**Details:**

1. The comments are all happening on the same page.
2. The comment plugin is implemented as follows:

> ```
> <script>(function(d, s, id) {
>       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
>       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>       js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=111111111111111';
>       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
>     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
>
>    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="THE_URL"" data-num-posts="6" data-colorscheme="light" data-mobile="auto-detect" data-width="744"></div>
> ```

**Question**

What can I do to test this plugin without getting shutdown by Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the functionality with test accounts, otherwise FB will treat as SPAM and disbale your account or APP.

Check the below links on how to work with test accounts.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/35/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

If you have an app that you created, while testing make sure it is in sandbox mode

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/112/

Comment: +1. I wasn't able to find these docs. Thanks Ram. I'm going to give this a try now. I'll reply with my findings.

Comment: I wasn't able to quickly get a hold of our APP KEY for facebook. So, in the meantime I continued troubleshooting. As it turns out, my problem was related to the domain from which I was interacting with facebook (likes, comments, etc.). I changed my domain name and was able to begin using the plugins again. I think this probably just fooled facebook's spam and fake account detection. In the end I suspect a test account would have saved me from this workaround.

Comment: Michael, this is very good information and helpful to other fellow community users could get benefit of. I wish FB provides more visible info on this rather than hidden privacy policy.